# GAS - set the default script to be loaded when opening a project

Tags: google-apps-script

When you open Google Apps Script, it always have one of your script files loaded already. It's usually the one named `Code.gs` (because it's the first file to exists when you first create the project), but I renamed it to `Main.gs` and now it isn't the one opened by default.

This may sound silly but it's inconvenient when you work with tools like [danthareja/node-google-apps-script](https://github.com/danthareja/node-google-apps-script) for local development and you have to constantly reload the browser, **and then** open the file you want.

Is there a way to select a default script to be opened when you open a google apps script project?

Comment: What do you mean by default script? Can you explain it more?

Comment: You create a blank apps script project. It comes with a `Code.gs`. You add more files to that project like `MyThingy.gs`. You close Chrome. Open it again, and open the project. The file that opens first is always `Code.gs`. I want to change that behavior so it opens a different one.